# Why setting one state will affact another state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

So my code looks like this, where I have two same states `state1` and `state2`. Clicking on the "change" button will set the state of state1, but in fact, the value of both states are changed, showing by clicking on the "Show" button. What is causing this issue?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface Obj {
  num: number
}

const App = () => {

  const [state1, setState1] = useState<Array<Obj> | null>(null)
  const [state2, setState2] = useState<Array<Obj> | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const a = [{num: 1} as Obj]
    setState1(a)
    setState2(a)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (state1 == null) return null
          const temp = [...state1]
          temp[0].num = 100;
          setState1(temp)
        }}  
      >
        Change
      </button>
      <button 
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(state1, '11');
          console.log(state2, '22');
        }}
      >
        Show
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Answer (score 3):

This is because JavaScript objects are passed by reference. Since your object:

```js
const a = [{num: 1} as Obj];
```

is passed to both state setters, both will reference the same object in memory essentially. So when you later update one of them by setting `obj.num = 100`, the change will affect both state arrays since they contain the same object. Using the array spread syntax in your `temp` variable only creates a *shallow* copy, the object inside is still the same. To ensure this doesn't happen, you can deep clone the object before passing it to the second state setter. For example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const a = [{num: 1} as Obj]
  setState1(a)
  // used map() and destructuring syntax here just to clone
  setState2(a.map((obj) => {
    const clone = {...obj, num: 100 }
    return clone
  })))
}, [])
```

Note that object spread syntax *also* creates only a shallow copy. If the objects in the array contain references to other objects you will have to clone those too using the same approach.

Comment: It is not pass **by** reference, It's always pass by value, but for objects, the value of the variable is a reference. See [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know. Essentially what this means is that if we change the whole object in one state1, it will not affect state2 but if we change the internals, it after both. I kinda knew this from experience but now have a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you, Jared and Irfanullah! That works fine now!